# With Nest.js, how to make Mongoose accept mixed scheme or multiple types in one scheme?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nestjs

Say I have this simple Mongoose schema of which you can find something similar in the [docs of Nest.js](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb).

```
class One {
  name: string;
  type: string;
}

class Two {
  hight: number;
  depth: number;
}

class Three {
  count: number;
  properties: object;
}

@Schema({})
export class SomeThing { }

export const SomeThingSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(SomeThing)
```

How can I make `SomeThingSchema` implement **one** of the above 3 classes at a time?

I expect I can't. If so, how to implement a mixed schema (as [Mongoose says](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed)) but in a way that works with above code syntaxes? Unfortunately Nest.js docs don't say how.

Answer (score 1):

You can create more models for the same collection.
You have to use different models but the data will be in the same place and you can validate and have all the features of the mongoose models/documents.

Something like this

```js
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const oneSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  type: String
})

export const oneModel = mongoose.model('OneThing', oneSchema , 'things')

const twoSchema = new Schema({
  hight: Number,
  depth: Number
})

export const oneModel = mongoose.model('TwoThing', twoSchema , 'things')

const threeSchema = new Schema({
  count: Number,
  properties: Object
})

export const oneModel = mongoose.model('ThreeThing', threeSchema , 'things')
```

To add the model to your syntax you can use JSDoc

```js
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

/**
 * @class MySchema
 * @extends mongoose.Document
 */
const MySchema = new Schema({ one: String })

// You can also add the methods or anything in this way
/** @alias MySchema.prototype.customMethod */
MySchema.method('customMethod', function() {})

export default mongoose.model('Mymodel', MySchema );
```

In your code you have to declare the

```js
/**
 * @type {MySchema & mongoose.Document}
 */
const newItem = new MyModel({one: 1})
```